# Can a group of individuals be each referred to singularly?

Tags: grammar

There are multiple peoples not on the list,

should I say:

I believe those who doesn't have their name on the list is clear.

or:

I believe those who don't have their names on the list are clear.

Comment: You could try *It seems clear who is not on the list*.

Comment: Neither is acceptable.Perhaps you're aiming for 'I believe it is clear who don't have their names on the list', but @WS2's suggestion is far better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are **people** not on the list**.**

**S**hould I say:

I believe those who doesn't have their name**s** on the list is clear.

or:

I believe those who don't have their names on the list are clear.

---

Don't use either one.

Since *those* is a plural pronoun, *don't* is correct.

But whether to use *is* or *are* depends on what you mean, and your meaning isn't clear.

- If the people not on the list are clear *about* something or clear *of* something, then *are* is correct.
- But if it's clear which names are missing from the list, than *is* is correct.

So you need to rephrase.

But that doesn't answer the original question: *Can **members of** a group of individuals each be referred to singularly?*

- Plural pronouns need plural verbs.
- Refer to each individual (each single person) singularly: Lucy is tired. Paco is bored.
- *Everyone* is singular (every *one*): Everyone *is* entitled to an opinion.
- In American English, a group is usually (*usually*) considered singular: The navy *is* retreating. The team *was* drunk.
- In British English, a group is usually (*usually*) plural: The committee *are* in disarray. The jury *were* deadlocked.

NOTES: Start sentences with capital letters. End sentences with periods, question marks, or exclamation points. The word *multiple* is usually unnecessary and wordy. *People* is plural for *person*, so (in most cases) don't add an *s*.

Answer (score 1):

> Can a group of individuals be each referred to singularly?

Yes, but not in the way that you have done it.

"**Who**" is a pronoun with the referent "**those**" - "**those**" is plural, therefore "**who**" is plural. And the verb agrees with the subject.

I believe **those** who **don't** have their name on the list is clear.

I believe **everyone** who **doesn't** have their name on the list is clear.

In British English, it is usually (*"usually" does not mean "always*) possible to (i) make the distinction and (ii) common to use the plural for a group. (One exception is "the police" which is always plural.)

"The government are doing everything **they** can".  "government" is considered as plural = all individual members of the government and civil servants, i.e. the current individual members of administration.

"The government is doing everything **it** can".  = the administration of a country as a whole considered as a single unit.

Answer (score -1):

I would say "don't". Compare it with the old chestnut "one of our aircraft is missing"/"one of our aircraft are missing" where the correct answer is "is missing" because you are only speaking about one aircraft. I think people also get it wrong when they say things like "the government are doing everything they can". To me, government is one entity so it should be "the government is doing everything it can" OR "the members of the government are doing everything they can". Hope this helps!

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Please take the [tour] and when you have a moment, read-up in the [help] about how we work. Your answer would benefit from referenced citations.

Comment: In a divisive backdrop, let's say,  'government are...'; unlike a unified backdrop like 'the government unanimously works for the people..' Similar is the usage of words like committee...

Answer (score -2):

You should go for the second sentence. The sentence would appear to be addressing multiple people as clear if they meet the condition of not being on the list, so I would refer to them using the plural forms.